# Semi-continued movement after Time.timescale = 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make text boxes pop up during my game and have it pause the game, and it seems to be working for the most part. There's a little bit of oddness with it that I've found and can't figure out what's going on: As long as I keep hitting the movement keys (particularly LEFT) I can keep moving.

My game is tile and turn based, so the movements are simply testing the map array and then jumping the character (as follows):

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Horizontal"))
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            if (TileArray.WalkableTile (newPosition.x + 1, newPosition.y) == true)
            {
                TileArray.ToggleWalkable (newPosition.x, newPosition.y, true);
                newPosition.x += 1;
                PlayerMoved = true;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            if (TileArray.WalkableTile (newPosition.x - 1, newPosition.y) == true)
            {
                TileArray.ToggleWalkable (newPosition.x, newPosition.y, true);
                newPosition.x -= 1;
                PlayerMoved = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The code I'm using to pause and display the text boxes is:

```
public void StartDialog(int Counter)
{
    Time.timeScale = Time.timeScale = 0;
    InDialog = true;
    DialogCounter = Counter;
    DialogCanvas.enabled = true;
    ClickCounter = 0;
    DialogText.text = DialogArray [DialogCounter][ClickCounter];
    UpdateDialogPic(DialogArray[DialogCounter][ClickCounter]);
}
```

It does not seem to matter whether the text is only 1 box or a chain of multiple text boxes that you cycle through using mouse clicks. Everything seems to be working fine aside from this, and it doesn't matter whether I wait to press left or not - as long as I don't stop once I START, I can walk the map or until I hit something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to note two main facts about `Time.timeScale`.

> When timeScale is set to zero the game is basically paused if all your
>   functions are frame rate independent.

and

> If you lower timeScale it is recommended to also lower
>   Time.fixedDeltaTime by the same amount.

You may make the following changes to your code,

```
// introduce a new variable
bool isPaused 

// for the pausing/resuming action
if(isPaused)
{
   Time.timeScale = 1;
   isPaused = !isPaused;
}
else
{
   Time.timeScale = 0;
   isPaused = !isPaused;
}

// On your 'if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Horizontal"))' line
if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Horizontal") && !isPaused)
```

Comment: Currently I have no animations whatsoever (very basic build) so nothing should be reliant on frame rates. The pause menu, dialog popup (which includes pausing functions), and the movement is handled in 3 separate scripts, all attached to different objects. Why would the timescale pause properly after I stop trying to move?

Comment: @user2237254 even `Update()` is frame rate dependent. This is the way you have to do it.Did you try this one?

Comment: I will try and incorporate the pause into my movement tomorrow as it's going to be a little more extensive. I did however try adding a time.fixeddeltatime toggle based on your comment (toggled between 0 and 0.02f which I found was the "normal" speed based on print) - that didn't end up helping and I had the same oddness.

Comment: Hey there, just wanted to say that putting in the bool check worked fine. I tested something else before I put that in - made this even more confusing. I set it up so you could trigger the popup pause menu WHILE inside the dialog pause. This worked for the first dialog trigger (at the start of the game to test), but not so well for a OnTriggerEnter after that. Ended up with what I said before, with added bonus that once I stopped trying to move (so not being allowed to move anymore) and i hit pause menu, I can move while in menu. Dropping out of pause menu locked move again, and is repeatable.

Comment: It worked with your method. I was just saying that I tried something else before that and it made the error weirder.